# Aplicación de prestamos en Java - Android Studio - Firebase

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, firebase-snapshot

Estoy haciendo mi primera aplicación de Prestamos en Java y Firebase, pero tengo un problema.

Creé un método que debería actualizar las cuotas de forma diaria. Consiste en un ciclo FOR que va desde 1 hasta la cantidad de prestamos activos. En ese ciclo, consulto la cantidad de cuotas del 1er prestamo, y se abre otro ciclo FOR que va de 1 hasta la cantidad de cuotas de ese prestamo en particular, pero cuando consulto en Firebase el estado de cada cuota y el monto abonado (lo pongo en 2 variables, "Pagado" y "Estado") no puedo usar esa información fuera de la consulta a Firebase.

```
        for (j = 1; j <= Cuotas; j++) {
        
        String ID = DNI + " - " + (NroPrestamo) + " - " + j + "-" + Cuotas;

        nFirestore.collection("Cuotas").document(ID).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                            Pagado = documentSnapshot.getLong("Pagado");
                            Estado = documentSnapshot.getString("Estado");

                            if(Estado!="Pagada"){
                            actualizarCuotas();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Si pongo el método dentro de la consulta, me da error y se cae la app. Si dejo el metodo fuera de la consulta a Firebase, pero dentro del ciclo FOR, corre bien y actualiza las cuotas, pero sin la información de las variables antes mencionadas.

Podrían ayudarme? Seguramente hay alguna forma mejor de hacerlo pero como mi experiencia es poca no sé cómo seguir...

Desde ya muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Las llamadas a Firebase son asíncronas, por tanto, no puedes usar los datos que defines en Firebase sin más, fuera del contexto en que los obtienes. Debes usar un callback o bien crear un objeto que sea miembro de la clase, informarlo dentro del contexto de Firebase (lo más práctico es mapear la respuesta de Firebase a un POJO) y luego usarlo fuera o bien pasarlo en parámetro a la función que llamas desde dentro de Firebase.

Comment: Otra cosa, **Firebase computa cada lectura de documento**, por lo que meter llamadas a Firebase dentro de bucles puede ser una verdadera ruina. Si tu bucle tiene 1,000 elementos, ese bloque de código implicará 1,000 lecturas a Firebase. En una App que la usen 50,000 personas, estamos hablando de 50,000 x 1,000 lecturas en un solo bloque de código. Te puedes llevar un gran susto en la factura si tuvieras un Plan Blaze, y si es un plan Spark tu App dejará de funcionar en cuanto a Firebase hasta el próximo mes. Debes tener mucho cuidado con la forma con que consultas a Firebase.